# How to count duplication items?

Tags: mysql

Every customer should not have duplicated code, as you can see the result below for example Customer-A have duplicated Code of `22` and Customer-D have duplicated Code of `44`

I like to run a query to get a number of how many duplications do we have, from the result below it should be 4. I have tried using `Group By` Code and `Having` but not having much luck.

```
customer         Code
------        ---------
  A               11
  A               22
  A               22
  B               33
  C               22
  D               44
  D               44
  D               44
  D               22
```

Comment: Why is your expected result 4? You have 2 dups for A and 3 for D.

Comment: @forpas it is code dups. There are 2 dups from A=22,22 and 2 dups from D=44,44. So it is 4 in total.

Comment: There are 3 dups from D=44,44,44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use group by and keep the combinations with more than one line

> ```
> create table t(
> customer  char(1),
> Code int);
> insert into t values
>   ('A',               11),
>   ('A',               22),
>   ('A',               22),
>   ('B',               33),
>   ('C',               22),
>   ('D',               44),
>   ('D',               44),
>   ('D',               44),
>   ('D',               22);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>   customer,
>   code,
>   count(*) "number"
> FROM t
> GROUP BY 
>   customer,
>   code
> HAVING 
>   COUNT(*) > 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> customer | code | number
> :------- | ---: | -----:
> A        |   22 |      2
> D        |   44 |      3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4e8bc7be92611eb0eae2a0911021abec)*

Comment: I don't understand how does this work especially using with `-` dash

Comment: It is returning 0 instead of 4

Comment: Because you did something wrong.  What is your actual query?